# How to use IRole in AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on AWS CDK. I have created one role as below.

```
 MWSAutoscalingRole = iam.Role(self, 'MWSAutoscalingRole',
        assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal('application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com'))

        MWSAutoscalingRole.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources=["*"],
        actions=["application-autoscaling:*"]
        ))
```

Now I want to assign this role to scalable target as below.

```
asg.ScalableTarget(self, id = "scalable target", min_capacity = 1, max_capacity = 1, resource_id = "service", role= [iam.IRole.role_name["MWSAutoscalingRole"]], scalable_dimension = "1", service_namespace = asg.ServiceNamespace.ECS)
```

In the above code, `role= [iam.IRole.role_name["MWSAutoscalingRole"]]` is not working. The right syntax for this is `role: typing.Optional[aws_cdk.aws_iam.IRole]=None`

The implementation above is not working. Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: You said "The above implementation is not working", but you also pointed out that you are using incorrect syntax, so that's probably why it is not working. Can you clarify what you're asking for help with? What are you expecting vs what happens? What did you try?

Comment: role= [iam.IRole.role_name["MWSAutoscalingRole"]] this line is giving error so I feel syntex i am using wrong

Comment: TypeError: 'property' object is not subscriptable This error I am getting. If i remove role property it works but I want to have role